# JavaScript if statement not working except inside function. Anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function that alerts the user when their amount of "moonstone" is 10. However, for various reasons, I would like the if statement to be outside the function. When I do this though, the alert doesn't work. Could someone please explain and post a fix for it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<img id="game-board" onclick="totalCount()" class="game-board" src="https://pics.clipartpng.com/thumbs/Mars_PNG_Clip_Art-3002.png"></img>
<h2 id="counts">Moonstone:</h2> 
<script>

let stone = 0;
function totalCount() {
let newCounts = stone++;
document.getElementById('counts').innerHTML= "Moonstone:"+ newCounts;
}

if (newCounts == 10){
alert('10');
}

</script>
</html>
```

What does work, but that I don't want to use, is

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<img id="game-board" onclick="totalCount()" class="game-board" src="https://pics.clipartpng.com/thumbs/Mars_PNG_Clip_Art-3002.png"></img>
<h2 id="counts">Moonstone:</h2> 
<script>

let stone = 0;
function totalCount() {
let newCounts = stone++;
document.getElementById('counts').innerHTML= "Moonstone:"+ newCounts;
if (newCounts == 10){
alert('10');
}
}


</script>
```

Comment: you need to look at scoping

Comment: It "doesn't work" because (1) you're trying to use the variable outside of the function where it's defined and (2) you're trying to use it only once immediately upon loading the page before it would ever have the value you're looking for.  If you already have a working version, what's the problem?  Why don't you want to use the working code?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you calling the totalcount() function on onclick event so whatever inside the totalcount() function will executed and code outside the totalcount() function will not  execute

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear why you wouldn't want the if test within the function.  But, there is something that you could do:

```js
    const counter = {
      value: 0,
      addOne: function() {
        this.value++;
        if (this.value > 10) {
          alert("Too many");
          this.value--;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("counts").innerHTML = "Moonstones: " + this.value;
        }
      }
    }

    function updateCounter() {
      counter.addOne();
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="updateCounter();">Add</button>
<div id="counts"></div>
```

This creates the counter as an object and includes an if test on a addOne function directly attached to that object.  Whenever the updateCounter() function is called, the addOne function updates the counter value and checks to see if it has passed 10.  If it has, the user gets and alert, otherwise the "counts" element gets updated.

But, as others have said, there is no real reason why an if test shouldn't be part of a function - perhaps you could explain your reasons for that requirement?

Comment: The reason I need it separate is that the code shown is a small part of a game I am making. Basically, the user unlocks new planets with their "moonstone." However, to do this, I need a function that checks the value of the variable stone, and alerts the user if they can buy the planet, or can't. The issue is that since the stone variable and counter are in a function, when I go to check their values in a new function to send the alerts and subtract the necessary stone from the user, it doesn't work.

Comment: The variables are defined in the function because that is where they have been defined.  You can define the variables outside of the function and update them within the function.  As they are then outside of a function, they are "global" and can be seen from any other function.  So, enter "let newCounts;" above the function and remove the "let" from the "let newCounts = stone++;" within the function.  newCounts then becomes visible to other functions